# vb.net designing questions

Tags: vb.net, textbox, checkbox, dynamic-tables

i have created a dynamic table through vb.net, so htmltable, htmltablerow, htmltablecell.
I have added all style and properties in there. so eg.

```
dim td as htmltablecell
td.style.add("width","100px")
td.style.add("color","blue")
```

now what i want to do is add the  tag to each row. this is because the first td of every row is a checkbox. and then textboxes follow. So when anyone clicks on the textbox, i want to checkbox to get checked.
Any idea how I can do this?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is near incomprehensible, consider revising?

> td.style.add("color","blue") now what i want to do is add the tag to each row

Since your table is dynamic, to add more styles and properties onto htmltablerow, you would do just as you did with your htmltablecells.

> So when anyone clicks on the textbox, i want to checkbox to get checked. Any idea how I can do this?

You're looking for what is called the on_click event for the textbox. Programatically, when this event is triggered, you check your checkbox. Here's [an example with a on_click in a textbox](http://www.startvbdotnet.com/controls/textbox.aspx).